# OpenCV drawing vs SVG rendering performance

Tags: c++, node.js, opencv, opengl, svg

I need to render vector graphics very fast to use it in OpenCV (in nodejs).

Fastest way to render simple shapes like oval is to use OpenCV drawing functions.
In my multithreaded test program I have ~625 1-channel 512*512 Mat's with 1 random filled oval per second.

With fastest available in nodejs SVG to PNG renderer 'librsvg' I have only ~277 same Mat's per second. It's not fast enough for my purposes.

I found another SVG renderer lib based on OpenGL - [SVGL](https://github.com/rev22/svgl), but I didn't test it's performance, there is no bindings for node, C++ only.

I will need to render much more complicated vector graphics than just one ellipse.

So I expect a lot of work if I will try to implement all the drawing functions I will need with OpenCV, and I am not sure if OpenCV performance will be still acceptable in case of complicated vector images.

"Complicated" I mean some hundreds of semi-transparent arcs, beziers or some kind of rounded polygons, not filled or filled with solid semi-transparent color or, possibly, with gradients. And I want to render it to pretty large Mat, may be 1024*768 or so.

SVG already has everything I need, but I don't know C++,
so it will(probably) also take a lot of time to implement bindings for SVGL, while I still don't know it's performance

May be there are some alternative opensource ways?

Comment: You don't tell us enough of how complicated your graphics are. What kind of primities ? What combinations ?

Comment: I edited a question to answer this

Comment: This is not using the techniques you're mentioning but   http://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php?log=171003000351

Comment: Is this example of using OpenGL for drawing 2D primitives?
Well, I can try something like https://github.com/mikeseven/node-webgl
but openGL is like new huge universe for me.. thanks for idea.